# split multidimension array for array intersection

Tags: php, arrays

I have a two dimension array filled dynamically by user:
ie.

```
var_dump($myarray)
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "80" [1]=> string(1) "5" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "60" [1]=> string(1) "5" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "62" [1]=> string(1) "5" } [4]=> &array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "53" [1]=> string(1) "4" } }
```

How can I separate the two dimension into individual arrays to be used at `array_intersect` for content comparison?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: @AbraCadaver You have a way better answer than mine :D, but I would do: `effort for answers` now

Comment: It's very doubtful that you need to separate them and that would be even more complex to use.  How about explaining how you want to use `array_intersect on these` and as @Rizier123 states, where's the effort?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$multi_array = array();

$i=0;
$multi_array[$i++] = array('80', '5');
$multi_array[$i++] = array('60', '5');
$multi_array[$i++] = array('2', '1');

$array1 = $array2 = array();
foreach ($multi_array as $index => $values){
    $array1[] = $values[0];
    $array2[] = $values[1];
}

$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the issue is similar to http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10288477-split-multidimensional-array-in-two ... my array contents are unpredictable.

Comment: quick and dirty:     for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {
       $subarray0[$i]    = $myarray[$i][0];
       $subarray1[$i]    = $myarray[$i][1];
}    $result = array_intersect($subarray0, $subarray1);

Comment: @MarceloJuniorCarvalho what do you mean by unpredictable? Can you show me sample arrays of your needs. It will really help me to provide you best script to handle all situations.

Comment: Tks Nouman. As I mentioned, the dirty code did the trick until a more fancy solution come up... by unpredictable I meant neither size or content from my arrays are known (upon user selection).